# Created image using imagick. Now i want to download it in pdf form

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

i have the following simple code .

```
 $image->newImage(194, 200, "red");
 $image->setImageFormat("jpg");
 header("Content-Type: image/jpg"); 
 echo $image;
```

I just want to convert this image to pdf in downloadable form. thanks

Comment: Or just change the image format to pdf and sent the right content-type (application/pdf). If you want to make it directly downloadable, sent the headers to force a download.

Comment: Can i do this conversion using imagick ? is imagick provide this facilty to convert images to pdf?

Comment: Tested my solution and my version of imagemagick can do this. Don't know about yours.

Comment: So kindly tell me how it does this? can you share your code please

Comment: It's your code with the changes I already posted. `$image->setImageFormat("pdf"),` and `header("Content-Type: application/pdf");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $image->setImageFormat('pdf');
 header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

This will simply generate the pdf file.. Incase you want to download use any simple download function for it...